# Setting up C++ include settings for a large library such as Paraview and QT in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, qt

I have an application where I am compiling against the libraries Qt (5.11) and Paraview (5.6). I am developing in C++ and I am also coding in Eclipse.

Yes, I am aware that Paraview is more of an application then a library. However, I will be using it as a library to intergrate Paraview in my application in order to visualize some data. I could use QT creator and that would take care of the QT library. However, I am not very familiar with QT creator as an IDE and my entire workflow has been based around eclipse. For this, I would like to utilize components that I am familiar with.

Now, as many of you know, the QT library is large, very large. So is Paraview. I could create a search path for each folder containing the header files I need in the C++ include settings. If I go in this direction, then my library search path will be long, very long. Also, there might be a situation where I need to change computers (for whatever reason), I would then need to edit the search paths for the new computer and that will take time.I had thought that I could only include the paths to the include files that I needed. And I have started to do that. However, when I compile my application, I noticed that the libraries would use include files that are located in a directory that Eclipse is not even searching in. At the end of the day, I would need to include all of the directories to which the header files are stored in.

I was wondering if there might be a better method to reference all of the files that my project needs? Both come with make files (I believe that Qt includes a QMake file?). Is there a simpler method to include all of the files instead of editing the C++ include path for eclipse? I did see an option for QMake in Eclipse, is there anything that I can do with that feature to compile to QT library with my application?

Thank you and any feedback is appreciated. Also, feel free to suggest edits or clarification so that my description is clear.

Comment: Yes! I am wondering the same thing! Although, I am using a different set of libraries but the same principal applis to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note some good practices when working with eclipse and qt or other large library.

### Include the directories with a headers

1. If you use option "Generate Makefile automatically", add group include path with GUI Eclipse:

   - copy the directories with a headers (via system explorer);
   - go to project properties/C/C++Build/Settings/Tool Settings/GCC C++
     Compiler/Includes.
   - paste directories (Ctrl+V) into "Include paths" list.

[image]

2. If you are using a qt-eclipse-integration plugin, you can add folders via the Discovered scanner configuration. You can find it if open: project properties/C/C++ Include Paths and Symbols/Add Contributed...

### Create new project

if you already have a customized project, you can use it as a template:

- make a copy of the customized project and name "mytempate";
- delete all files from "mytempate".

When you want to create a new project, copy the template and specify (in the copy dialog) the path where the source codes are located. 
Now you have a finished new project with settings and code.

### Change computers

Use one of the ways:
1. Export C/C++ project settings for use in another workspace via project properties/C/C++ General/Paths and symbols/Includes/Export Settings...
2. Pack in the archive eclipse and workspace and copy your another computer.